# Print the result of a regex in Python

Tags: python

I need to search through user created AWS policies to see if there is one with a user name in it.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import re
def create_iam_policy(user_name,aws_account):
     session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
     client = session.client('iam')
     response = client.list_policies(Scope='Local',OnlyAttached=False)
     print(str(re.search(user_name, response).group()))
```

But when I do that I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: where is "user_name" coming from?, it ain't declared anywhere.

Comment: What are the values of `user_name` and `response`?  What do you see if you remove the `str()` from the `print()` call?

Comment: This is a response: https://pastebin.com/MEUv1uNm. The user name I'm using is 'bluethundr'

Comment: An advice to OP: I've seen a few of your questions and they generally suffer from a lack of basic programming concepts and misunderstanding of object types or what the functions are supposed to do, etc.  I'd highly suggest you to brush up on your foundation before approaching higher concepts or you will continue to be plagued by these issues.

Comment: @Idlehands is it not the case that people ask questions to learn?

Comment: @SamuelNde definitely.  I am not discouraging OP to stop asking, but it should be in the right direction.  It seems OP's question often are due to misunderstanding of these basic concepts, so brushing up on that would alleviate a lot of their headache.  It is an observation, not meant as an insult or unwelcoming message.

Comment: @Idlehands You are right. I felt so at some point. The difference is I have been a teacher and I am used to getting such questions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching in is a `dictionary or a json object` not a `string`. You might want to change

```
print(str(re.search(user_name, response).group()))
```

to

```
print(re.search(user_name, str(response)).group())
```

The `response` is **not a string and so you cannot search it using `re`.**

Comment: Since the json object is a dictionary (in this case nested dictionary), you will have to know the keys and use the keys to get the values. If you put a sample response, I will help you search for username.

Comment: What exactly did you want the sample response to give you? I don't  know what your username is. And by the way, the response does not contain a username. Try `response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']` and see the result.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong response I posted. This is the response I need to search through. I'm looking for the user name 'bluethundr' in hte following json output: https://pastebin.com/42yiv67P

Comment: @bluethundr Please chechout boto3 documentation page linked below. The response has no attribute called `username`. 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_policies

But if you really want to get your username, it should be at the end of your `arn` and `PolicyName`. Try the code snippet below and you should get the user name.
`response['Policies'][0]['PolicyName'].split('-')[-1]`
`response['Policies'][0]['Arn'].split('-')[-1]`